# Is there a way to get exact file path when uploading a file?

Tags: angular, hibernate, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I'm working on a web application where user can track question papers. For that, the user will locate the .zip file in the system and the file will be stored in the DB along with other details of the question paper. I'm using forms in Angular 4.

But the path which I'm getting is `C:\fakepath\....` How to get the exact file path so the back end can read and write the file in DB. I m using Hibernate and Java for the back-end.

Also is there a way where I can restrict a specific type of file to be uploaded. Thank You

```
<div class="form-group row">
      <label for="file" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Select File:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input type="file" class="form-control" formControlName="file"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get exact file path when uploading a file.

You need read binary content of file uploaded in Java code and save it to your folder which is configurable in your web server.

Is there a way where I can restrict a specific type of file to be uploaded, you can add accept attribute `accept=".png,.jpeg"`

```
<input type="file" accept=".png,.jpeg" class="form-control" formControlName="file"/>
```

Comment: If i cant get the path of the file then it will taken a lot of time to search for the file in the computer. Is there a way to get the file quickly which will save time rather than checking the whole system or fixing a fixed folder of uploading.

Comment: why you need search file in computer? when you read content from blob and save to folder you configured?

Comment: when i m submitting the form i m getting this values:  {qpName: "sadasd", batchType: "Interns", faSelection: "FA-1", qpReviewer: "Mr. XYZ", file: "C:\fakepath\SessionStorage.zip"} How will i get the file location in the back end to read and store it